# why the offset and limit

Tags: facebook, limit, offset

Facebook simulator test https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?limit=50 return to the 16, switched to https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?limit=1&offset=9, but no data is returned.
If offset changed to 8,it will return a data. How this is going, who can help me?
The amount of data is enough, but it can not use limit and offset to display all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [facebook blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) explains how the limit and offset parameters work and also the limitations of them.

Use time-based paging instead of “offset” to ensure you are getting back as many results as possible with each call. For these Graph API connections, use the “since” and “until” parameters.